# Move Map in Android V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have implemented Google maps v2 for Android app. My location, marker everything is showing fine, but when I am on move **OnMylocationChange** is called and marker is updated, but I have to scroll up or down as the view of my location goes off the map.

How do I update my map to scroll with my current location? Like Google Maps App.

```
@Override
public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) 
{

    if (markermylocation != null)
    {
        markermylocation.remove();
    }

    curlat = location.getLatitude();
    curlong = location.getLongitude();

    myLocation(curlat, curlong, username, imageURL, ZOOMVALUE);
}


private void myLocation(double lat, double lng, String name, String url, float zoom)
{
    if(firsttime  == 1)
    {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat,lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        googleMap.animateCamera(update);
        firsttime = 0;
    }

    final String uname = name; 
    curlat = lat;
    curlong = lng;

    Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(url).resize(120, 120).transform(transformation).into(new Target() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) 
        {
            markerOptionsmylocaiton = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(curlat, curlong)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.profilepic)).title(uname).anchor(0.5f, 1f);
            markermylocation = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptionsmylocaiton);          
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap b, LoadedFrom arg1) 
        {

            bitmapMarkermylocation = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(b);

            if(b != null)
            {
                markerOptionsmylocaiton = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(curlat, curlong)).icon(bitmapMarkermylocation).title(uname).anchor(0.5f, 1f);
            }
            else
            {
                markerOptionsmylocaiton = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(curlat, curlong)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.profilepic)).title(uname).anchor(0.5f, 1f);
            }

            markermylocation = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptionsmylocaiton);       
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) 
        {

        }
    });
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have to remove the if (firsttime == 1) conditional, then the map should recenter whenever your location is updated.

```
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat,lng);
    CameraUpdate update = null;

    if(firsttime  == 1) {
        update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        firsttime = 0;
    } else {
        update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
    }
    googleMap.animateCamera(update);
```

is there a reason you have that in there?

Comment: The problem is when I zoom out to check other markers.. It automatically changes to my location and hence I can't see them zooming again. There other reason is that. I read somewhere that animateCamera usually should be used the first time and doesn't require onMyLocation change.

Comment: i updated my answer to reflect you comment,  this __should__ just zoom the first time, so if you zoom out it will just recenter the map.  ultimately you need to manage the camera to make it do what you want.

Comment: @ nPN - It is working with map moving to my current location, but the problem is that before the zoom gets to my first time location it gets to else part and hence the zoom for first time doesn't work at all. :(

Comment: I made some changes to your logic and it is working now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: good to hear, I was going to suggest maybe using moveCamera the first time or you could look into using one of the versions of animateCamera with a callback that gets run when the animation is complete.  basically you just have to play around until you get the desired visual effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in spec:

> CameraUpdateFactory is a class containing methods for creating CameraUpdate objects that change a map's camera. To modify the map's camera, call animateCamera(CameraUpdate), animateCamera(CameraUpdate, GoogleMap.CancelableCallback) or moveCamera(CameraUpdate), using a CameraUpdate object created with this class.
>   [read more](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html)

so when you are implementing this :

```
markermylocation = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptionsmylocaiton);
```

take care of camera move with this methods:

```
// Showing the current location in Google Map
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

// Zoom in the Google Map
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```

Comment: @ Ali Abdolahi : But the problem is that I when zoom out the map is positioned immediately to my location so I will not be able to zoom out again. How do I solve that issue with your solution.

Comment: try to test, UiSettings class which can be obtained from a GoogleMap by calling GoogleMap.getUiSettings and then use UiSettings.setZoomGesturesEnabled(true) to enable zoom gestures

Comment: check this url for UiSettings: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/UiSettings.html